# Why Valgrind segfaults when I launch a new thread

Tags: c++, multithreading, segmentation-fault, valgrind

I'm writing a program in C++ and I noticed something very odd.

When I run my program under Xcode everything works fine, but when I do that under Valgrind it gives me a `segmentation fault` after a few seconds.

I managed to extract a very simple code that gives me that error:

```
#include <thread>

void exec_1() {}

int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {

    std::thread simulator_thread;
    simulator_thread = std::thread(exec_1);
    simulator_thread.join();

    return 0;
}
```

What I'm doing is simply building my executable under Xcode with these flags:

**CFLAGS:**

```
-I/usr/local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/numpy/core/include
-I/usr/local/Cellar/python3/3.6.1/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/include/python3.6m 
-Wno-unused-result -Wsign-compare -Wunreachable-code
-fno-common -dynamic -DNDEBUG -g -fwrapv -Wall -Wstrict-prototypes
```

**LDFLAGS:**

```
-L/usr/local/opt/python3/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin
-lpython3.6m -ldl -framework CoreFoundation
```

and then run the executable under Valgrind to find memory leaks. You'll see that I'm calling the `Python C API` because I'm using it in my `main` code but this code throws me the `segfault` without using them.

Anyway Valgrind, along with some other stuff, gives me the following output:

```
Thread 2:
==41660== Invalid read of size 4
==41660==    at 0x1016FA899: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==    by 0x1016FA886: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==    by 0x1016FA08C: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==  Address 0x18 is not stack'd, malloc'd or (recently) free'd
==41660== 
==41660== 
==41660== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==41660==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==41660==    at 0x1016FA899: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==    by 0x1016FA886: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==    by 0x1016FA08C: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==41660==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==41660==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==41660==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==41660==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==41660==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--41660:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
```

Is it possible that spawning a thread under Valgrind is the cause of the error?

**P.S:**
My OS is `MacOS 10.12.5` and I'm using `Xcode 8.3.3` and `Valgrind 3.13.0`.

Comment: Is there any difference if you add the -pthread flag to your CFLAGS and LDFLAGS ?

Comment: Not related to your problem, but you should almost always prefer initialisation to assignment. Use: `std::thread simulator_thread( exec_1);`

Comment: @NeilButterworth You're right. But in my main program I spawn more than one thread by creating an empty array of `std::thread` and then assigning them a real object with a `for` loop. Here I tried to keep the structure as close as possible to my main code

Comment: @nos Doesn't change anything

Comment: Did you resolve this? I'm having the same problem

Comment: @JamieBullock Nope, I'm sorry:( I couldn't figure out the problem and so I didn't use Valgrind anymore

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Is it possible that spawning a thread under Valgrind is the cause of the error?

It appears that this is indeed a problem with Valgrind on Mac OS X when running binaries that use pthread:

*Access not within mapped region in _pthread_find_thread (OS X 10.11)*
https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=349128

Your failures with Valgrind look similar to what was reported here:

[std::thread.join() SIGSEGV on Mac OS under Valgrind](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36576251/stdthread-join-sigsegv-on-mac-os-under-valgrind)

Comment: I see it's a quite old bug. I hope they fix it soon. Thank you!

Comment: Still not fixed :(

Answer (score 4):

I'm still facing the same problem with macOS 10.12.6 + Valgrind 3.13.0.

```
==82699== Process terminating with default action of signal 11 (SIGSEGV)
==82699==  Access not within mapped region at address 0x18
==82699==    at 0x10058E899: _pthread_body (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==82699==    by 0x10058E886: _pthread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==82699==    by 0x10058E08C: thread_start (in /usr/lib/system/libsystem_pthread.dylib)
==82699==  If you believe this happened as a result of a stack
==82699==  overflow in your program's main thread (unlikely but
==82699==  possible), you can try to increase the size of the
==82699==  main thread stack using the --main-stacksize= flag.
==82699==  The main thread stack size used in this run was 8388608.
--82699:0:schedule VG_(sema_down): read returned -4
==82699== 
==82699== Events    : Ir
==82699== Collected : 30468496
==82699== 
==82699== I   refs:      30,468,496
Segmentation fault: 11
```

Just found that there is another bug tracking https://bugs.kde.org/show_bug.cgi?id=380269. 
This is really a historical bug. Hope it won't take another 2 years to get fixed.